# Reading classpath from hosted app from a maven plugin

Tags: maven, plugins, classpath

I need to build a maven plugin in which I need to access the classpath of the app where I include this plugin... Is there any API to access the classpath ?. I have all the logic to parse it but no to access it...

Thankx

Comment: Sorry don't understand what you like to do ? And in particular what kind of problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I have an app "Alerts" which have several Rest controllers... I need to build a maven plugin that access the classpath and read those rest controller classes and then creates a txt file with some info... The thing is that, there is a plugin already but cant seem to install it (Swagger); because we arent so much in a hurry I would like to do this in the weekend...

Comment: I could read the classpath of my hosted app from my maven plugin. Now I have another problem: If in my hosted app I have a class "com.sports.soccer.Manager", I can create a class object from it to inspect it because it throws a classnotfoundexception. Is there any way to create that class object ?. If this works, I would be done.